# Hide the verbose Serialized Error in Vitest test output

Tags: typescript, vitest

Vitest test output contains a serialized copy of the error at the end of the test output.

This means I end up having to scroll up each time to see what caused it.

Is there some configuration to control whether it is shown?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Are you able to fix this issue I am also facing the same issue? Please let me know :)

Comment: @sabithakuppusamy might want to add your thoughts here github.com/vitest-dev/vitest/issues/2976